# Chaining update and get method in Django for updating fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django Model as follows:

```
class IPGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    junos_space_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Jira(models.Model):
    jira_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ip_groups = models.ForeignKey(IPGroup, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Now I have a atomic ORM transaction as follows:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic(): 
        IPGroup.objects.filter(id=2).update(junos_space_id=3)
        Jira.objects.filter(jira_id=2)).update(ip_groups_id=2)
except Exception:
    response = Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                        data={'status': 'Database error encountered'})
```

This works well when everything is fine.However, when an error occurs as in case of an wrong id, **filter** just gives an empty queryset and it never hits the exception.

I tried re-writing it with a **get** instead of a **filter** as follows:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic(): 
        IPGroup.objects.get(id=2).update(junos_space_id=3)
        Jira.objects.get(jira_id=2)).update(ip_groups_id=2)
except Exception:
    response = Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                        data={'status': 'Database error encountered'})
```

But is gives me the following attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'IPGroup' object has no attribute 'update'

What is the best way to doing this in a clean way ?

Comment: `filter()` returns a Queryset (which might be empty) and `update()` only works on `QuerySet`s. So split your line in 3: fetch the object first, then change its attribute and save. And don't use `except Exception`, but `except (IPGroup.DoesNotExist, Jira.DoesNotExist)` so you are more specific about the type of exception to catch. I would never return a 500 error in that case but a 404 (page not found) error or just a  friendly user error. It's not a database error anyway to query for a non-existing object.

Comment: As an aside, you may run into trouble in the future if you assume hard-coded `id`s to be the same in every installation you have (assuming they're regular Django autoincrement `id`s). You should consider some sort of secondary unique identifier or slug, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to break up your code into 3 steps

1. first `get` then next update

   ```
    ip_group = IPGroup.objects.get(id=2)
   ```
2. Update the field

   ```
    ip_group.junos_space_id=3
   ```
3. save it

   ```
    ip_group.save()
   ```

for reference [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Happily, [`update()` returns the number of rows matched by the query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), so if you do want to use `.update()` instead of loading, updating and saving the object like @AJS's answer suggests, you could do something like

```py
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        if IPGroup.objects.filter(id=2).update(junos_space_id=3) == 0:
            raise ValueError("No IPGroups matched")
        if Jira.objects.filter(jira_id=2).update(ip_groups_id=2) == 0:
            raise ValueError("No Jiras matched")
except Exception as exc:
    response = Response(
        status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        data={"status": "Database error encountered: %s" % exc},
    )
```